# Liquibase Move Column Database Refactoring

Tags: database, liquibase

Is there a standard way in Liquibase to migrate a column from one table to another existing table (including data)? What is want to do is this database refactoring: http://databaserefactoring.com/MoveColumn.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is not support for that refactoring currently. You would be able to create one through the extension system, however (http://liquibase.org/extensions)

Comment: Did you ever write the extension?

Comment: So did anyone really wrote the extension :''D

Comment: Not that I know of so far.